# Filter values from HashMap<Integer, List<Object>> using Java8 concepts

Tags: java-8, stream

**My input:**
A hashmap with structure `HashMap<Integer, List<Parent>>` where `List<Parent>` can have instances of Child objects inside it.

**My Expectation:**
Using Java8 streams concept extract a subset of the `HashMap<Integer, List<Parent>>` where objects inside the List are `instaceOf Child` Class and  `finder` attribute of Child class has a specific value (ex. test)

**Example:**
*Input*

> {
> 1=[Child [finder=test], Parent [], Child [finder=test]],
> 2=[Child [finder=text], Parent [], Parent []],
> 3=[Child [finder=test], Child [finder=test], Parent []]
> }

*Output*

> {
> 1=[Child [finder=test], Child [finder=test]],
> 3=[Child [finder=test], Child [finder=test]]
> }

**Code**

Below is my class structure where there is `Parent class` and a `Child class`. Also there is `Hashmap` object where key is an Integer and values as `List<Parent>`.

```
class Parent {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parent []";
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public String finder;
    
    public Child(String f) {
        this.finder = f;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child [finder=" + finder + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test data

```
Map<Integer, List<Parent>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, List.of(new Child("test"),new Parent(),
        new Child("test"), new Child("Foo"), new Parent()));
map.put(2, List.of(new Parent(), new Child("text")));
map.put(3, List.of(new Parent(), new Child("Bar"), 
        new Child("test"), new Parent()));
```

Process

- first map the map entries to individual entries of the key and each value element of the list.
- then filter on instance of Child and finder type.
- the group on key (integer) and put children into a list

```
Map<Integer, List<Parent>> map2 = map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap((Entry<Integer, List<Parent>> e) -> e
                .getValue().stream()
                .map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                        e.getKey(), v)))
        .filter(obj -> obj.getValue() instanceof Child && 
                ((Child)obj.getValue()).getFinder().equals("test"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue,
                        Collectors.toList())));

map2.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
1=[Child [finder=test], Child [finder=test]]
3=[Child [finder=test]]
```

I added a getter to the Child class to retrieve the finder value.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)